# Epsilon-N limit Proof for product law for limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Let the $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n=a$ and let $\lim_{n\to \infty} y_n=b$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ for some $n\ge N$

My notes says: $|(x_n)(y_n)-ab|=|x_n(y_n-b)+b(x_n-a)|$

Can someone show me the intermediate steps to the LHS of the equation?

Answer (score 0):

Just distribute: Notice

$$ x_n(y_n-b) + b(x_n-a) = y_nx_n - x_nb + bx_n - ab = y_nx_n - ab $$

This is just a trick.

In order to show that $x_ny_n \to ab$ provided $x_n \to a$ and $y_n \to b$, we must show by definition that for any $\epsilon > 0$, we can find some $N > 0$ such that if $n > N$, then

$$ |x_ny_n - ab | < \epsilon $$

That is the reason why the starting point is $|x_ny_n - ab|$, because we want to bound this term.

Comment: I understand the trick. My question was how |(x_n)(y_n)-ab| was arrived at besides the algebraic manipulation.
What was the motivation?

Comment: @guest $|x_ny_n-ab|$ is not arrived at, it is the starting point of the proof. In order to show $x_ny_n\to ab$, you have to show $|x_ny_n-ab|<\epsilon$ for $n\ge N$, so you start with $|x_ny_n-ab|$, then manipulate it until you can show it is less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: Admittedly, "arrived" was a poor and illogical choice of word. 
What is the motivation for  |xnyn−ab|?I want to know why that is the starting point for the argument.

Comment: guest: see my update.

Comment: So it is just:
x_n=a,y_n=b
so,
(x_n)(y_n)=ab<epsilon
[(x_n)(y_n)-ab]<epsilon

Then, manipulate LHS
. . .

Comment: Would it be plausible, also, to directly attempt 
|(x_n)-a| |(y_n)-b|?

Comment: @guest Please see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to typeset stuff correctly, even in comments.